# Is google.load for jquery / jquery.ui outdated?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I just had a strange run-in with google.load from the Google js.api, and loading jquery and jquery-ui.

When I use google.load

```
google.load('jquery', '1.7.1');
google.load('jqueryui', '1.8.17')
```

these versions are the highest I can get, otherwise it throws an "Error: Module: 'jquery' with version '1.8.1' not found!" and similar.

It works however with including the files in a script-tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

On [Google Hosted Libraries](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide) there is no mentioning of google.load as an alternative, though I could swear there was one some time ago. However, on [Google Loader](https://developers.google.com/loader/), the example still has jquery and jquery-ui in it. Did Google forget to update the page? And if you are not supposed to load libs with load anymore, when was this change introduced?

Comment: There is no jquery 1.8.2 released. The latest major one is 1.8.1

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I meant 1.8.1. However, the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, jquery 1.8 is not in the Google Loader

If you go directly to https://www.google.com/jsapi you will see at the bottom all of the supported versions and that 1.8.1 does not exist.

Comment: Thanks, so it's at least not only a local problem. I asked in a google group to find more information.

Comment: @Narretz, yeah they might give more info.  Personally I recommend not using Google Loader as its one more web request to load its script... just so it can load some more.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
google.load("jquery", "1.7.1");
```

Comment: I made a mistake with the jQuery version. But that doesn't change the problem - I cannot load 1.8.1 either with google.load

Comment: I tried this before; in fact, I tried every version from the latest downwards, and the ones in my post are the highest that work. Did you try it yourself, and did it work then? Maybe it's a a local issue, but I doubt it.